# Teams Tab apps error - Refused to display 'https://somedomain.sharepoint.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

While redirecting teams tab App to the SharePoint site such as Viva app , above error is appearing the tab. this is only happened for the Microsoft 365 user accounts. is there any reason where sharepoint.com is already allowed in manifest ?

**redirect url**
https://devacc.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/teamslogon.aspx?spfx=true&dest=https://devacc.sharepoint.com/sites/HomeSite?app=portals

**manifest**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.9/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
    "manifestVersion": "1.9",
    "version": "1.0.0",

 ....
 ....
 
    "validDomains": [
        "{teamSiteDomain}", 
        "*.login.microsoftonline.com",
        "*.sharepoint.com",
        "resourceseng.blob.core.windows.net"
    ],
    "webApplicationInfo": {
        "resource": "https://{teamSiteDomain}",
        "id": "bbc6d1e2-2233-4dc7-1122-0eaa862aaccc"
    },
    "isFullScreen": true
}
```

Comment: We are checking this internally. Update you soon

Answer (score 1):

Browsers same-origin policy restriction prevents webpages from making requests to different domains than the served web page.

So, you can redirect the configuration or content page to another domain or subdomain. Your cross-domain navigation logic needs to allow the Teams client to validate the origin against a static validDomains list in the app manifest when loading or communicating with the tab.

Ref Doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-requirements